# How to get install() in devtools to look for dependencies in several .libPaths

Tags: r, installation, devtools

I am using the install function in the devtools-package to handle installation of an R-package I am building, to conveniently handle installation within R.

My .libPaths() setup is as follows: The first directory-path in .libPaths() is where I install my own packages and packages not on CRAN., while the second directory-path contains a lot of common packages from CRAN, installed by sysadmin.

I wish to install my package it in the first directory-path in .libPath(), look for packages in all .libPaths() and only install those packages which are not to be found in any of them. However, running install() (or install_github()) in devtools re-installs packages in the first directory-path, which I already have installed in the second directory-path in libPaths(). That is NOT the desired behavior, and very ineffective as my package depends on quite a lot of other packages.

When running "R CMD INSTALL package" from the command line, only packages not found in the second (or first) directory-path are installed (in the first one). This is the desired behavior, and how I want install in devtools to operate.  None of the input arguments to install() seems to fix this behavior.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to accomplish the command line behavior with devtools-install? That is make install() look for dependencies in other  .libPaths() directories before deciding to install them?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with R version 3.3.1.

Any pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated.